# Not able to download large files

Tags: php, drupal

I'm using the following code to download files. When I use this code with small files, it works. But if I just point to to a large file ~2GB, the same code fails to download the large file.

```
$file_name = 'myfile.tar.gz';
$file_url = $base_url.'/sites/default/files/vss/Windows/myfile.tar.gz';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

Any clue will help.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to run using chunked files but I'm still NOT able to open the archive file that is downloaded. I tried multiple times but every time I get the same error:

> Cannot open the file as [gzip] archive 
>   Is not an archive

the code which I'm using is:

```
// Read a file and its content chunk by chunk
function readfile_chunked($filename, $retbytes = TRUE) {
    $buffer = '';
    $cnt    = 0;
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    if ($handle === false) {
        return false;
    }
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, CHUNK_SIZE);
        echo $buffer; 
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        if ($retbytes) {
            $cnt += strlen($buffer);
        }
    }
    $status = fclose($handle);
    if ($retbytes && $status) {
        return $cnt; // return num. bytes delivered like readfile() does.
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: is this a 32bit system?

Comment: I don't have access to the logs and It's a 64 bit system.

Comment: Not having access to the logs is a problem, you need some way to see the real error. It could be something as simple as an execution timeout to you forgetting to turn off output buffering and a number of other things.